# Android. Open same fragment, when pressed a notification with save backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation

I want to restore my backstack(A-B) and open new fragment (C). Problem with Navigation Component =( When my application is working in background and I click by notification --- >MainActivity created with new NavController

I try

```
val pendingIntent = NavDeepLinkBuilder(context) .setComponentName(YourActivity::class.java) .setGraph(R.navigation.your_nav_graph) .setDestination(R.id.your_destination) .setArguments(bundle) .createPendingIntent() 
notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
```

But I am not able to recreate the backstack with this soultion. I have Fragment A -> B -> C when I use this solution the graph is only A -> C

Comment: I don't get you 100%. You want to land on Fragment C from a graph that has Fragment A as start destination and you want to open B (which is not in the backstack) when you press back on fragment C?

Comment: I want to restore my backstack(A-B) and open new fragment (C). Problem with Navigation Component =( When my application is working in background and I click by notification --- >MainActivity created with new NavController

Comment: I try val pendingIntent = NavDeepLinkBuilder(context)
                     .setComponentName(YourActivity::class.java)
                     .setGraph(R.navigation.your_nav_graph)
                     .setDestination(R.id.your_destination)
                     .setArguments(bundle)
                     .createPendingIntent()

//then

notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent) But I am not able to recreate the backstack with this soultion. I have Fragment A -> B -> C when I use this solution the graph is only A -> C